# Need to parse a string of ints and get the white space

Tags: c++, parsing, int, whitespace, stringstream

I have a file filled with ints (variable amount on a line), delimited by a space. I would like to parse out the int, then space, then int, then space ... until the newline char then start at a new line until the eof. An example file would look something like this:

```
1 1 324 234 12 123 
2 2 312 403 234 234 123 125 23 34
...
```

To grab the ints I can do something like this:

```
std::ifstream inStream(file.txt);
std::string line;
int myInt = 0;
while(getline(inStream, line)) {
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    while(ss) {
        ss >> myInt;
        //process...
    }
}
```

My question is that is there an easy way to also get the whitespace and endline char from the ss? Or is my best bet to write my program assuming a space after each index and a newline at the end of the ss? something like this:

```
std::ifstream inStream(file.txt);
std::string line;
int myInt = 0;
while(getline(inStream, line)) {
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    while(ss) {
        ss >> myInt;
        // process...
        // done with myInt
        char mySpace = ' ';
        // now process mySpace
    }
    char myNewLine = '\n';
    // now process myNewLine
}
```

Comment: Do you expect the white space between the numbers to be different from `' '`?

Comment: No. between the numbers it will always be one whitespace. Thats why I can hard code for it if needed, but If there's an easy way to grab it from ss I would prefer that.

Comment: If it is always a single `' '` then why bother trying to extract it at all? Fake it. Let the `stringstream` swallow whitespace and line break for you. Read an 'int', and if not at end-of-stream yet then assume a `' '`, and then when end-of-stream is reached assume a `'\n'`.

Comment: If you really want to get a handle to the next character, [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) will be a good function to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If performance is not the most important issue, the following would be a general-purpose tokenizer for your input format.  Whether this is a feasible solution depends of course on what you actually want to do with the input.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

static void handle_number_string(std::string& literal) {
  if (!literal.empty()) {
    std::istringstream iss {literal};
    int value;
    if (iss >> value) {
      std::clog << "<" << value << ">";
    } else {
      // TODO: Handle malformed integer literal
    }
    literal.clear();
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    std::string aux;
    std::ifstream istr {argv[i]};
    std::clog << argv[i] << ": ";
    while (istr.good()) {
      const int next = istr.get();
      switch (next) {
      case ' ':
        handle_number_string(aux);
        std::clog << "<SPC>";
        break;
      case '\n':
        handle_number_string(aux);
        std::clog << "<EOL>";
        break;
      default:
        aux.push_back(next);
      }
    }
    // Handle case that the last line was not terminated with '\n'.
    handle_number_string(aux);
    std::clog << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Addendum:** I'd only do this if I absolutely had to. Handling all possibilities (multiple spaces, non-breaking spaces, tabs, `\r\n`,…) correctly will be a lot of work.  If what you actually want to handle are the logical tokens *field separator* and *end of line*, manually parsing whitespace seems to be the wrong way to go.  It would be sad if your program crashes just because a user has justified the columns in the input file (thus using a variable number of spaces).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
std::ifstream inStream(file.txt);
std::string line;
int myInt;
while (std::getline(inStream, line))
{
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    ss >> myInt;
    if (ss)
    {
        do
        {
            // process...
            // done with myInt

            ss >> myInt;
            if (!ss) break;

            char mySpace = ' ';
            // now process mySpace
        }
        while (true);
    }

    char myNewLine = '\n';
    // now process myNewLine
}
```